# How to get email address for external Attendee

Tags: c#, .net, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

I'm working on application, one of features of which is synchronizing Exchange appointments to application database. For some attendees, Address property returns string which looks like LDAP path (e.g. `/O=Foobar Exch Org/ou=Exchange Administrative Group (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT)/cn=Recipients/cn=Yuriy Rozhovetskiy`)

Does the EWS Managed API provides a way to resolve email address for such attendees?

Edited:
This is an external attendee, and it can't be found not by ResolveName, nor by search in LDAP

Answer (score 1):

Actually that is an Exchange address (type EX). You can try doing a `ResolveName` to resolve it in your directory. You might also try calling `Appointment.Bind` on the item, the server does some resolving of addresses for you in this case.

Comment: Unfortunately, nor ResolveName not Appointment.Bind didn't resolved issue.

Comment: @Yuriy Did you use the proper SearchScope for ResolveName? ActiveDirectory / ActiveDirectoryContacts / Contacts / ContactsActiveDirectory

Comment: @JanDoggen yes, I did. Basically, I tried all options with no result

Answer (score 0):

This path is not really an e-mail address, just the user identifier in the directory and there is not much your application can do with it.
You should be looking for addresses which start with SMTP:.